# 220V universal motor Arduino control

Tags: arduino, universal-motor

I bought a 220V 100W sewing machine motor to use in a project.

I thought that the motor works only on AC because 220V  is written on it, but I tried it with 30V Dc and surprisingly it spun.

1. Is that enough to know that this motor is a universal motor?
2. If it is a universal motor, what is the best way to power it to get full power with 220V DC ? Maybe a rectifier bridge?
3. I don't want to work with AC voltage because it is hard to control (for me) and it needs TRIAC trimming with zero cross detection to work with an Arduino so can I just use an Arduino and a MOSFET to control the motor with 220V DC? What is the best MOSFET for this thing?

Comment: A rectifier does not create DC, but sine-pulsed DC, so you need to care for the zero-crossings in any case.

Comment: Yes, it you want speed control you need to look for zero crossings, else if just on/off control use a TRIAC driver with built-in zero-cross detection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes the fact that the motor works with DC applied pretty much proves that it is a universal motor. The only other possibility is that it is another type of DC motor such as a permanent-magnet DC motor with a commutator or a DC shunt motor. However those types of motors will not work on AC. If there is an indication that will work on either AC or DC, it can only be a universal motor.
2. With 220V and a rectifier bridge, you can get a bit more than the rated speed and torque from a universal motor. Universal motors work sightly better with DC than with AC.
3. For speed control of a universal motor, you can modulate rectified 220 VAC or a lower DC voltage using any appropriate DC switching device and PWM. A lower voltage will limit the maximum speed and power.

See also::

[How does the power usage and voltage of a universal motor change when running on DC?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/277614/how-does-the-power-usage-and-voltage-of-a-universal-motor-change-when-running-on)